# Render html from a template with rendering a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am sending a fax through a Fax API module I built.

The plan is to mix it into my Fax model and just call `self.send_fax`. The Fax table itself will have a `fax_number` column which it expects along with a `recipeint name`. In order to send this.

One more thing it needs to expect is `raw_html`. The way I'm thinking about doig this would be to create an `attr_accessor` for it and when the Fax object is created inject it with all the HTML that it needs.

How can I call render from the controller without actually rendering a view, just processing it and adding the result to the column?

Does this method of solving the problem make the most sense? Can you think of a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is the `render_to_string` method. It works just like `render` in your controller, but it returns the rendered view HTML as a string, instead of sending it in the response body.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string

Comment: Wow. Completely forget about that method. It's even in the Rails guides. Mad props.